# Fee-Based Online Financial Planners

Tags: online-tools, financial-advisor

I've looked at some online financial planners (e.g. Personal Capital) and it looks like all of them charge based on a percentage of the portfolio being managed.

I am looking for a site to help create a financial plan, but I would be fine with implementing it myself.

Does anyone know of one that is purely fee-based?

Comment: As asked, the question (asking for a specific service recommendation) is off topic. I'm closing but with link to similar question whose answer might help.

Answer (score 0):

One that I am familiar with is Wealth Logic by Allan Roth. I have gotten a lot of good advice from him on the [bogleheads forum](https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/index.php) and my understanding is that Wealth Logic is fee-only hourly for creation of a plan.

http://daretobedull.com

Comment: Thanks @jmg229.  At the very least, they have an awesome URL.